# moment js to convert date from one format to other

Tags: momentjs

I am using moment js to convert date variable format

```
moment("23MAY68", 'DDMMMYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
moment("23MAY99", 'DDMMMYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Until the year 68, the output is 2068. From the year 69, the output is 1969 and not 2069. Is there a syntax or parameter in moment.js where I can mention it to use 2069 and not 1969?

http://plnkr.co/edit/ljXuskMsUAuJnpkqMPUn?p=preview

Comment: Note that you used two digit for the year in the plunker code, while you are using four digit here.

Comment: I updated the year value to 2 digits now

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From moment docs:

> By default, two digit years above 68 are assumed to be in the 1900's and years 68 or below are assumed to be in the 2000's. This can be changed by replacing the `moment.parseTwoDigitYear` method.

So if you replace `moment.parseTwoDigitYear` in you code, you will have 2069 instead of 1969.

Here a working example:

```js
moment.parseTwoDigitYear = function(year){
  return parseInt(year, 10) + 2000;
};

var s1 = moment("23MAY68", 'DDMMMYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var s2 = moment("23MAY99", 'DDMMMYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

console.log(s1, s2);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Since there is a four-digit year in the input, this is unnecessary.  But it's a good approach for when the year is only two digits in the input.

Comment: I suggested this solution because the OP used two digit year in the linked plunker

Comment: That makes sense then.  Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 14):

Yes there is. Just parse with the correct format

```
moment("23MAY2099", 'DDMMMYYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```